# How to add 200 tablets to Samsung Knox?

Tags: samsung-knox

I want to purchase 200 tablets (Samsung Galaxy Tab A 2016 - SM-T580) and configure them using Knox Configure. The easiest way to register so many devices is to purchase the tablets directly from a certified Samsung dealer. My problem: I get the tablets much cheaper at a "non Samsung dealer".

Suppose I had the 200 tablets unpacked in my office: does anyone know if the IMEIs are visible on the outside of the packaging? I would hate to open 200 boxes, start 200 devices and go through the whole Android setup procedure manually, just in in order to read the corresponding IMEIs from the Settings. But if I could read the IMEIs directly from the outside of the unopened packaging, I would take the trouble to type 200 IMEIs manually into Knox Configure (that would work, wouldn't it?).

Can anyone tell me if that would work? Or would there even be an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are only two ways to register devices in the Knox Configure portal.

1. Through a samsung certified reseller where they can do it automatically after the purchase.
2. Manually using the Knox Deployment app where you will need to have every single device turned on and with the initial setup complete because you will need to use the web browser. You can follow this guide to use the app: https://support.samsungknox.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015643127-Knox-Deployment-App-User-Guide

Comment: Thanks Filipe. I found all the official Knox sources rather hard to understand since to me it's a lot of marketing speech. Anyways: I had the following discussion which might help others: https://emm.how/t/how-to-add-200-tablets-to-knox-configure/841/5